# How do I render an EJS template file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm using Node.js and trying to render an EJS template file. I figured out how to render strings:

```js
    var http = require('http');
    var ejs = require('ejs');

    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        res.end(ejs.render('Hello World'));
    });

    server.listen(3000);
```

How can I render an EJS template file?

Comment: So you can render a string, why not just read the template file in as a string and take it from there?

Comment: The fact is, I'm so new to node.js I don't know how to read files :D. Maybe it's too early for me to start using template engines...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var templateString = fs.readFileSync('template.ejs', 'utf-8');
```

and then you do your thing:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.end(ejs.render(templateString));
});
```

Answer (score 54):

There is a function in EJS to render files, you can just do:

```js
    ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/template.ejs', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err || data);
    });
```

Source: [Official EJS documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)

Comment: The renderFile function in EJS is documented as of 2020, it's on their main documentation page (in the Usage section): https://ejs.co/#docs

Comment: Using promises, e.g. `const html = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, {extraData})` is probably the way to go nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is compile the file as a string (with optional local variables), like so:

```
var fs = require('fs'), ejs = require('ejs'), http = require('http'), 
         server, filePath;
filePath = __dirname + '/sample.html'; // this is from your current directory
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
  if (error) { throw error); }
  // start the server once you have the content of the file
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // render the file using some local params
    res.end(ejs.render(content, {
      users: [
        { name: 'tj' },
        { name: 'mape' },
        { name: 'guillermo' }
      ]
    });  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

@*ksloan*'s answer is really good. I also had the same use case and did little bit of digging. The function renderFile() is overloaded. The one you will need mostly is:

```
renderFile(path: string,data, cb)
```

for example:

```
ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/template.ejs', dataForTemplate, function(err, data) {
console.log(err || data)
})
```

where *dataForTemplate* is an object containing values that you need inside the template.

Answer (score 3):

There's a synchronous version of this pattern that tightens it up a little more.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var filePath = __dirname + '/sample.html';
    var template = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    res.end(ejs.render(template,{}));
});
```

Note the use of **readFileSync**(). If you specify the encoding (utf8 here), the function returns a string containing your template.

Comment: Doing this on a real server would heavily impact performance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @ksloan should be the accepted one. It uses the ejs function precisely for this purpose.

Here is an example of how to use with Bluebird:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var path = require('path');
var ejs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('ejs'));

ejs.renderFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'template.ejs'), {context: 'my context'})
  .then(function (tpl) {
    console.log(tpl);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

For the sake of completeness here is a promisified version of the currently accepted answer:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var path = require('path');

fs.readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'template.ejs'), 'utf-8')
  .then(function (tpl) {
    console.log(ejs.render(tpl, {context: 'my context'}));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ejs.renderFile(filename, data)` function with **async-await**.

**To render HTML files.**

```
const renderHtmlFile = async () => {
    try {
        //Parameters inside the HTML file
        let params = {firstName : 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
        let html = await ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/template.html', params);
        console.log(html);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured: ", error);
    }
}
```

**To render EJS files.**

```
const renderEjsFile = async () => {
    try {
        //Parameters inside the HTML file
        let params = {firstName : 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
        let ejs = await ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/template.ejs', params);
        console.log(ejs);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured: ", error);
    }
}
```