# Passing a variable from the Server (Node.JS) to the Client

Tags: javascript, node.js

How is it possible to send a variable from the Server Side to the Client Side in Node.JS?

I have an app.js file and a public directory which holds an index.html template.

The app.js uses a basic server and the `readFile` function to open and display the HTML template.

The problem is I want to display a MongoDB query result on the client side in index.html

How is this possible, without the use of a framework such as Express, as I am trying to avoid that.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to use template engine (ejs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/render-ejs-file-in-node-js)

Comment: It seems highly relevant: _Why_ are you avoiding "a framework like X?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do string replacing yourself or use a template engine which is mostly optimized for doing this.

Template engines: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-templating