# Render EJS and save it to Redis

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In my Node-Express app I'm using Postgre as main data and Redis as cache system.

When a visitor request an url, my app request the json to Redis. If isn't available, make a request to Postgre, save the json to Redis and then render the EJS template. The next request to the same url, I get the json from Redis and render the template.

Now I want to save to Redis the full rendered template instead of json to save CPU usage. I tried this trick but it did not work:

[Render ejs file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/render-ejs-file-in-node-js/14146082#14146082)

Any ideas or suggestions how to do it ??

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Express API reference shows that [res.render()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) accepts a callback as the last argument. That callback is called with `(err, html)`, so just pass in a callback and store the (string) `html` into redis.

Comment: your answer work great for me. Now I can save to Redis and even print to console the rendered HTML... but the user get a timeout. Apparently not send the rendered template response to the browser.

This is how my function look now:

    res.render('home.ejs',{
        host: appConfig.app.url + '/'
    },
    function(err,html)
    {
        if (err) return console.error('Error running query',err);
        redis.setex(rediskey,redisexp_2h,String(html));
        console.log(html);
    });

Comment: Yes, when you add the callback, that stops the automatic response to the client. So you'll have to manually do `res.send(html);` inside the callback.