# How to publish ejs website using winscp?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, webpack

I built a nodejs web application that is based on ExpressJS and the start point of this website is app.js.

I want to publish this website on a domain using winScp. WinScp requires index.html file as the start point in order to publish the website.

Can we use something like webpack or browserify to bundle the application and publish the website or is there any solution?

Comment: Whats the host that you are using ?

Comment: www.domain_name.edu/course_name is the url. The hosting is provided by the University. I do not have much information on the same.

Comment: WinSCP is, AFAIK, an SCP/FTP client. You should be able to just copy the files over file by file if nothing else. Just don't use their "publish website" tool. Their documentation is horrible, I admit, but here's a starting point: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_upload

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I found out that you can render the ejs

ejs is a template engine that makes it possible to load data from your app in the view. After you render the template, it generates .html file for the browser

official ejs documentation:https://ejs.co/#features

Use: Pass EJS a template string and some data. BOOM, you've got some HTML.

```
    let ejs = require('ejs');
    let people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];
    let html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
```

answer from more experienced stackoverflow contributors:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/how-do-i-render-an-ejs-template-file-in-node-js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/how-do-i-render-an-ejs-template-file-in-node-js%5D)