# What's the difference between EJS's render() and renderFile()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    var app = express(); 

    app.engine('ejs', ejs.renderFile);

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index.ejs', {
        title: 'Index',
        content: 'This is Express-app Top Page'
      })
    });

    var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('server start port: 3000');
    });
```

I was using `ejs.render()` method to render an EJS template string in Node.js (without using a framework). But I found `ejs.renderFile()` method used as a view engine in the Express framework. I can't find any difference between the two methods.

Comment: already asked question for render in ejs
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8660659/11011676)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using EJS with Express, you don't need to bother with `render` or `renderFile`.

You could also do:

```js
    // Set EJS View Engine
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

You can also refer to the [Express template guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

By this approach you are still using the `renderFile` method.

As for difference between these 2 methods:

- `render()` takes a string as a template and is a *synchronous* method.

```html
    <pre><code>ejs.render(str, data, options);
    // => Rendered HTML string
    </code></pre>
```

- `renderFile()` takes a file path as input, is *asynchronous* and takes a function call back.

```html
    <pre><code>ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function (err, str) {  
        // str => Rendered HTML string
    });</code></pre>
```

Comment: I think str in ejs.render is like './src/temp.ejs' and filename in ejs.renderFile is like  ‘./src/temp.ejs'.   so 1st and 2nd argument are same in both methods right?
Then The  differences are asynchronous or not and to take a function call back or not right?

Comment: @Kazu25 No `render` takes the actual template as string and `renderFile` takes the file path. Also to use relative paths for views you could use `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/views'));`

Comment: @ Aakash    "render takes the actual template as string and renderFile takes the file path. "    Could you give me coding sample for this?  actually, I cant understand

Comment: @Kazu25 So, render is used like `ejs.render('<p><%= text %><p>',{text:'hello word'})` and for renderFile you do `ejs.renderFile('full/path/to/file',{text:'hello world'},callback(error,str))`

Comment: @ Aakash I understand. I appreciate you

Answer (score 0):

As you see from Doc:

```
let template = ejs.compile(str, options);
template(data);
// => Rendered HTML string

ejs.render(str, data, options);
// => Rendered HTML string

ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});
```

https://ejs.co/#docs

that means:

`ejs.renderFile` - work with files and get path to file like argument

`ejs.render` - work with string template