# Nodemailer - cb is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i create an function to send email with `nodemailer`, but after run my console throw me:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Maciek\Desktop\GoParty\backend\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:226:12)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Maciek\Desktop\GoParty\backend\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:437:10)
    at Object.fn (C:\Users\Maciek\Desktop\GoParty\backend\api\controllers\user\create.js:47:28)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

my function to sendEmails.js

```
const transporter = require('nodemailer').createTransport(sails.config.custom.email)

module.exports = {
    inputs:{
        to: { type:'string', required:true },
        subject: { type:'string', required:true},
        html: {type:'string', required:true}
    },
    exits:{
        success: {
            description: 'All done.'
          }
    },

    fn: async function(inputs, exits){
        const options = {
            from: sails.config.custom.email.auth.user,
            to: inputs.to,
            subject: inputs.subject,
            html: inputs.html
        }

        transporter.sendMail(options, (err, info) => {
            if(err){
                return exits.error(err)
            }else return exits.success(info.response)
        })
    }
}
```

my create.js where i must send email with correct variables:

```
    const ejsVariable = {
      activeCode: inputs.activateCode
    }
    // const html = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, ejsVariable)
    // const subject = 'EventZone - potwierdzenie rejestracji'
    // const res = await sails.helpers.email.sendEmail(inputs.email, subject, html)
    // if(!res){
    //   return this.res.badRequest('Confirmation email has not been send.')
    // }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: ```const html = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, ejsVariable)```

Comment: Seems like your code is crashing from the `await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, ejsVariable)` line, not from nodemailer. From the stack trace it says it crashes on `Object.exports.renderFile \node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:437:10)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I render an EJS template file in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/how-do-i-render-an-ejs-template-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ejs.renderFile` takes 4 parameters, the last one is a function. Example usage:

```
ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});
```

it doesn't return a promise so you can't `await` it.

try replacing

```
const html = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, ejsVariable)
const subject = 'xxx'
const res = await sails.helpers.email.sendEmail(inputs.email, subject, html)
```

with

```
ejs.renderFile(templatePath, ejsVariable, async (err, html) => {
    const subject = 'xxx'
    const res = await sails.helpers.email.sendEmail(inputs.email, subject, html)
})
```

**UPDATE**

you can use `util.promisify` to make the `ejs.renderFile` function return a promise and thus work with async await like so:

```
const util = require('util') //first import `util`

....

const asyncEjsRenderFile = util.promisify(ejs.renderFile)
const html = await asyncEjsRenderFile(templatePath, ejsVariable)
const subject = 'xxx'
const res = await sails.helpers.email.sendEmail(inputs.email, subject, html)
```

Comment: What do I have to give instead of these parameters in the renderFile? what is filename, data and options in my project above?

Comment: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: i edited my post to show you all of my code in create.js

Comment: ah yeah i forgot to add async

Comment: now i have this `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: sails.helpers.email.sendEmail is not a function`

Comment: sorry bro... :(

Comment: it's okay, you have some bugs in your code, try targeting them one by one, we just fixed the first error, try fixing them one by one. And remember, now that we have a callback after ejs.renderFile, the variables created inside are local scoped and won't be accessed by the remaining code after it, if you need these scoped variables, then put the remaining code inside this callback

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think it's better than the callback style