# Why is express failing to lookup ejs file in views folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Started learning `NodeJS` and `Express`.

```
// express framework 
var express  = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", (req,res) =>
{
    res.render("home.ejs");
})

//port listening 
app.listen(3000, ()=>
    [
        console.log("Server listening at 3000")
    ])
```

The views folder is present in the same folder of the code and has the file `home.ejs`.

I receive the following error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "home.ejs" in views directory "/Users/username/Desktop/Programming/JavaScript/views"
    at Function.render (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/username/Desktop/Programming/JavaScript/practice/app.js:8:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/username/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I render an EJS template file in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/how-do-i-render-an-ejs-template-file-in-node-js)

Comment: Did you add the line `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`?

Comment: tried adding the line `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` but it does not help.

Comment: It works for me. see https://repl.it/@nthnchu/LiquidEvergreenDiscussion#index.js

Comment: I think it may be because of the version of express or something that makes it work for you without adding the lines in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Someone suggested adding.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

That did not work in itself but then I looked around and found that I also needed to add the following line.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

The tutorial I was following did not have any of this code so I was a little confused.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of express are you using? This should be the default in v3-v5 according to the website

Comment: I use the following version **express@4.17.1**

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. According to http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table that's the default (technically it's `process.cwd() + '/views'`, but that shouldn't affect anything.)

Comment: Ya...thats what I had thought and never figured to add those lines before...